# Maven parent dependency not found

Tags: java, maven

After update of version of dependency I get this error: `Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.3.1.RELEASE' not found` . Here is my code:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: did you do `mvn clean install -U`?

Comment: Are building on plain command line? If so please show the log output...

Comment: Generally when I use mvn clean install everything works fine, it compiles without any errors. It just Intelij shows red line with the error.

Comment: Run you command with `-e` switch and post the stacktrace.